# Return data from console application

Tags: c#, console

Is it possible somehow to return from Console application "Object"? Xml or Json representation of the object. I know that CLR will look for entrypoint static function that it Should be void or int during execution of Console app.

But is there any common way to return somehow object? 
Stdout stream?
Any ideas?

Comment: are you looking for `Console.Out`!Play with `Console` class to know more!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your object in a serialized form to the console. And other application can read this console output and deseralize the object.

Something like:

App1:

```
 Console.Write(Json.Serialize(obj));
```

App2:

```
var p = Process.Start("app1.exe");
var obj = Json.Deserialize(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Is this a common way to do it , i mean this is not kind of workaround right ? That's was a solution that i thought to do , but i was doubt about it..

Comment: Serializing to JSON may be just for convenience, but generally reading from other program's standard output is a typical means for communication between console application.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect to either File or other Memory Stream object. From there you can create your XML or JSON object. See this link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput